# Why did Alex, an aspiring dancer, choose welding as her day job?

Tags: plot-explanation, flashdance

In *Flashdance (1983)*, here we can see *Alex* is working at some welding company:

[image: Alex welding]

And she also working as dancer at dance club (not nudity because she against it), until her boyfriend fires her to continue dating her. Her dream is to be dancer. Welding is a risky job that doesn't suit a dancing girl role.

[image: Alex dancing]

Comment: Probably suits the "dancer girl role" this way - it's work she can find, it's work that has a decent paycheck.  While I'm sure she wished there was a "dancer girl"- specific job, welding jobs or similar types of work are (or at least were) probably more commonly available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashdance):

> Flashdance was inspired by the real-life story of Maureen Marder, a construction worker/welder by day and dancer by night in a Toronto strip club. Like Alex Owens in the film, she aspired to enroll in a prestigious dance school.

I don't see why a woman or a man couldn't do both jobs. Arc welding is a safe occupation when proper precautions are taken. One job doesn't prevent a person from working at something else.